# Kruskal's algorithm

Tags: beginner, algorithm, graph, coffeescript

I'm working through Coffeescript implementing simple algorithms (started with Prim's as reviewed in this [previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107095/prims-algorithm-in-coffeescript/107198?noredirect=1#comment196752_107198)) and wrote out Kruskal's algorithm as below, with a few helper functions. I'd appreciate any and all feedback, especially on making this script more idiomatic.

```
# 
# graph information
#

nodesDir =
0 : [1],
1 : [0, 2, 3, 5],
2 : [1, 4],
3 : [1, 4, 5],
4 : [2, 3],
5: [1, 3]

edgesDir = {
0: {1:6}
1: {2:1, 3: 2, 5:0, 0:6},
2: {1:1, 4:4},
3: {1:2, 4:5, 5:3},
4:{2:4, 3:5},
5:{3:3, 1:0},
}

edgesConDir =
0: [1,5],
1: [1, 2],
2: [1, 3],
3: [3, 5],
4: [2, 4],
5: [3, 4],
6: [0, 1]

NUM_NODES = Object.keys(nodesDir).length
NODES = [0...NUM_NODES]
MAX_WEIGHT = 10000
EDGE_WEIGHTS = [99, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 10]

# 
# helper functions
#

sortByKey = (array, key) ->
    array.sort((a, b) -> a[key] - b[key])

# returns array where all array elements previously 
# equal to before are set to after
convertAll = (array, before, after) ->
    ((if el != before then el else after) for el in array)   

# source: https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/chapters/arrays/removing-duplicate-elements-from-arrays
Array::unique = ->
  output = {}
  output[@[key]] = @[key] for key in [0...@length]
  value for key, value of output

# 
# traversal algorithm
#

# Kruskal algorithm as implemented in Skiena 198
kruskal = (nodesDir, edgesDir) ->
    edgesReturn = []
    edges = ( {i:i, weight:el} for el, i in EDGE_WEIGHTS)
    nodeComponents = ( i for el, i in NODES )
    sortByKey(edges, 'weight')
    nodesUn = nodeComponents.unique()
    while nodesUn.length > 1
        newEdge = edges.shift()
        nodesToTry = edgesConDir[newEdge.i]
        if nodeComponents[nodesToTry[0]] != nodeComponents[nodesToTry[1]]
            edgesReturn.push newEdge.i
            nodeComponents = convertAll(nodeComponents, nodeComponents[nodesToTry[1]], nodeComponents[nodesToTry[0]])
            nodesUn = nodeComponents.unique()
    edgesReturn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: *I don't know coffeescript, but I do know a little javascript*

Most of the code is understandable, even for me not knowing coffeescript, but it is obfuscated by bad naming and laziness. So I would opt for better naming a lot of places:

- `el` to `edge` or `element` or even better names
- `nodesUn` rename to `uniqueNodes`
- `edgesConDir`, `nodesDir` and `edgesDir`, maybe rename to `edgeConnections`/`nodeConnections`, `nodes` and `edges`?

I would also fix the spacing, so that it is consitent. In the three lists/dictionaries/... at the top you vary between having spaces around `:` or not. Personally I like to see stuff with spaces *after* the separators, so I would try to be consistent with using `5: {3:3, 1:0}` (that is spaces after at least the initial colon and after commas.

It seems like your code might be faulty as you have braces around the `edgesDir` but not around the two others? Are the braces optional? If so, it would look better if you used the same for very similar lists.

Regarding that last code block I would perhaps include a little more vertical space. And possibly, it it's legal, replace the `nodesToTry` with `fromNode, toNode = edgesConDir[newEdge.i]` or similar. That would make the following lines easier to read, I think.